# How to say " I understand what he said at that time "?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am confused about saying something about my past. The scenario is, I met with my teacher, and discussed my concerns about marks in exams. After a few months, my friend met me and asked about that meeting. How do I say to him that I'm satisfied with his arguments?

```
He makes me satisfy
```

or

```
He made me satisfy?
```

and in the same scenario, he again asked me whether I called the teacher after that?

So can I reply to it like

> I didn't call him since semester finished.

Comment: But what is your specific language concern? Verb tenses? Aux. verbs? You should edit your question with that information. Just asking how to say something is proofreading, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Correct grammar would be "He made me satisfied." However, to say that someone "made me satisfied", or "satisfied me" is often used as a sexual inuendo.

But you could say,

> I am satisfied with what he told me.

without anyone giggling in the background.

As for your other sentence, if you mean that you did not call because the semester finished, you could say,

> I didn't call him since the semester finished.

Or

> I didn't call him because the semester finished.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sentences are grammatically incorrect.

Just use the simple past of **satisfy**

> I was **satisfied** by the teacher's arguments.
>   I was **satisfied** by the teacher's explanation.

which means the teacher's answer was satisfactory for you. Note that this usage tends to be more BrE (from my experience), AmE speakers may say "I was happy with the teacher's explanation" or "The teacher's had an explanation which I'm happy with".

If you say

> I didn't call him *since* the semester finished.

it will probably be understood to mean you haven't called since a particular time (semester end), without giving a reason.  However, if you say

> I didn't call him *because* the semester was over.

you give a reason why you haven't called.

Comment: On the last bit: "since" can also mean "because". But since it can mean both (see what I did just there?) "because" might be a better choice in that sentence. Although I would expect a native speaker would *probably* say "I haven't called him since" if they were referring to a time period rather than a reason.

Comment: @Peter check your answer, I think there is a typo "I was satisfied "but" the teacher's explanation." but should be by

Comment: Still my question is, is it wrong to use 'makes' like he makes me satisy. For the past ?

Comment: "He makes me satisfy" is incorrect grammatically or at least incomplete since there is no object to "satisfy", "He makes me satisfy my hunger" is correct" and might refer to the past (repetitive) or the present. He makes me satisfied" is also correct, however it has a meaning which these days is more sexual in meaning as in "He satisfies my sexual appetite".